# Chart JS: All Values Displayed on x-axis After Callback Conversion

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I want to use Chart.Js to plot some data against days. The days will run from day 169 (Week 24 day 1) to day 295 (Week 42 day 1).

I want all data displayed for all days but only a subset of days on the x-axis as follows. I want the days on the x-axis to be displayed as the week AND for only the first of each week to be displayed. For example day 169 will display as week 24, then no values on the x-axis until day 176 which is week 25. I want **every** week to be displayed in this fashion on the x-axis.

I managed to convert the days to weeks on the x-axis using this callback function:

```
ticks: {
//stepSize: 10, //This does nothing
callback: function(dataLabel, index) {
//Hide the label of the datasets except the beginning of the week. Display the 
week, not the day. Return null to hide the grid line, or '' to keep it.
return (dataLabel - 1) % 7 === 0 ? (Math.floor((dataLabel - 1) / 7)).toString() : null;
},
```

This **does** seem to work in that all of the days I want to be converted to weeks are converted to weeks and the rest are returned as null (displaying no value on the x-axis and no line). I can tell this by manually resizing the chart and from the console log I have used. However, Chart Js seems to choose how many of these converted weeks to display. I tried to use the stepSize value to no avail. Is there any way to force Chart.JS to add all of these converted weeks on the x-axis?

Please see this JsFiddle for a demonstration:
https://jsfiddle.net/Brett_Riverboat/6hkqb1yj/5/
Line 215 is the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by disabling the autoSkip feature. Something I had tried previously but could not get to work. Presumably, because I put it in the wrong location.

```
      xAxes: 
        [{
            ticks: 
            {
                callback: function(dataLabel, index) {
                    //Hide the label of the datasets except the beginning of the week. Display the week, not the day. Return null to hide the grid line, or '' to keep it.
                    console.log("dataLabel = " + dataLabel + " (dataLabel - 1) % 7 " + (dataLabel - 1) % 7)
                    return (dataLabel - 1) % 7 === 0 ? (Math.floor((dataLabel - 1) / 7)).toString() : null;
                },
                fontSize: 16,
                autoSkip: false,
            },
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Week'
            }
        }]
```